# How can I use vispy with a newer OpenGL version?

Tags: vispy

I am trying to use an application based on vispy. It says

```
WARNING: OpenGL version 2.1 or higher recommended, got 1.1.0.
```

and then in fact fails with

```
RuntimeError: Function glBindFramebuffer not present in context (OpenGL version is 1.1.0).
```

To be honest, I do not have any background in vispy and OpenGL and the like. I tried to install PyOpenGL 3.1.0 in different ways, but it does not change anything. It appears that the vispy installation does not take any notice.

So how can I provide the vispy instance with a new OpenGL version?

I am working on Windows 7, using Anaconda Python 2.7. Any help would be appreciated.

Best,
Maik

Answer (score 0):

After all, it turned out that the reason for the above behaviour was that I had been working on the machine via the Remote Desktop client.

Working on the machine directly, the problem just went away - though I am not sure *why*.